# How to store value of inner for loop in nested for loop in an array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, nested

```
pvec = 1:3;
    for i = 1:3
      p=pvec(i);
        for m = 1:p
        erfun=erfc(5/(2*sqrt(p-m)));
        suma(m) = sum(erfun)
        end
    end
```

I want to save sum of all values of erfun for every p i.e I want to have 3 values in final array but every value in the array should be sum of all the values of erfun for one p. 
Similar questions have been addressed but I could not apply them in my case.

Comment: try replace `suma(m) = sum(erfun)` with `suma(i) = suma(i) + sum(erfun)`

Answer (score 1):

**Minimal fix method (to your own code)**

The following modification to your code will yield your requested results

```
suma = zeros(3,1);
pvec = 1:3;
for i = 1:3
  p=pvec(i);
  for m = 1:p
      erfun=erfc(5/(2*sqrt(p-m)));
      suma(i) = suma(i) + erfun;   %// <-- modified here
  end
end
```

Where I've also included `suma = zeros(3,1)`, which I assume that you also have in your code (however not shown in your question); pre-allocating `suma` with sufficient entries.

**Alternative method (`arrayfun`)**

Another solution, you can make use of the [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) command to get rid of the inner `for` loop:

```
suma = zeros(1,3);
pvec = 1:3;
for i = 1:3
  p=pvec(i);
  suma(i) = sum(arrayfun(@(x) erfc(5/(2*sqrt(p-x))), 1:p));
end
```

**Alternative method #2 (`arrayfun`)**

An even more condensed solution, including also the purpose of the outer `for` loop in your `arrayfun` call:

```
suma = arrayfun(@(x) ...
    sum(erfc(5./(2*sqrt(kron(x, ones(1,x-1)) - 1:(x-1))))), pvec)
```

Here we've made use of the [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) command, which will be implicitly used in the `arrayfun` command above as follows

```
kron(1, []) = [] %// empty array
kron(2, [1]) = 2
kron(3, [1 1]) = [3 3]
```

and used the fact that `erfc` addition from `1/sqrt(0)` is always `0` (i.e., `erfc(Inf) = 0`, and hence we needn't evaluate the case `m=p` as it yields no addition to our sum).

---

**Result**

All of the above methods yield the result

```
suma =

         0
    0.0004
    0.0128
```

Comment: In your first suggestion, it seems that for every value of p you are adding value that was calculated for previous value of p. For example for p=3 , third element of suma will have, new value added to the value which was calculated for p=2.

Comment: @AtherCheema That is not the case: note that `suma` is a (row) vector of 3 elements: for the inner for loop (`for m=1:p`), the value of _element_ `suma(i)` is updated, but **note that `i` is fixed for each separate run of this inner for loop**, as `i` is the indexing variable of the _outer_ for loop. Hence, e.g. `suma(3)` will only get additions for `p = pvec(3)`, and `p = pvec(2)` will have no effect whatsoever on the value in `suma(3)`.

Comment: Could you please also suggest in this case: `x = 100; 
l = 300; 
p = 2;
omega= x/l; deltaH = 0.2;
deltat = 5; 
v = 140; 
u = x/sqrt(v*deltat); suma = 0;
for m = 1:p
  for n = 1:1000
  e1Arg = (2*(n-1)*u + u*omega) / (2*omega*sqrt(p-m));
  e1 = erfc(e1Arg);
  e2Arg = (2*n*u - u*omega)/(1*omega*sqrt(p-m));
  e2 = erfc(e2Arg);
  totalerror = e1-e2;
  f = (-1)^(n-1) * deltaH * totalerror;
  suma = suma + f;
  end
end` The two loops calculate one value of `suma`, If `p=5` I want 5 values of `suma` with different values of `deltaH` which will be an array then.